# After Spring boot server initialization,it throws InvocationTargetException and ApplicationContextException

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am a newbie to spring and I am trying to implement a simple Spring boot application which will parse a json string and write it to a file.

Here is the code of my main class

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

//@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }


    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }

    private static Class<Application> applicationClass = Application.class;
}
```

The rest controller definition is below

```
package com.example;
import java.io.*;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class Controller {

    @RequestMapping(path="/api",consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String insertData(@RequestBody String rawJsonData,HttpServletRequest request) throws ParseException, IOException{
        JSONParser jparser=new JSONParser();
        Object jsonObj=jparser.parse(rawJsonData);
        JSONObject jObject=(JSONObject)jsonObj;

        FileWriter filewriter=new FileWriter(new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Aayushi.txt"));
        filewriter.write(jObject.toJSONString());
        return rawJsonData;

    }
}
```

The `updated` pom.xml file is as defined below

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>API</groupId>
  <artifactId>API</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
        <plugin>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
             <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
         </configuration>
         </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
   <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency><!-- Add tomcat only if I want to run directly -->
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <start-class>com.example.Application</start-class>
         <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

If I run this code as Run as->Maven Build, then I get the following errors and I am not sure why these errors are coming.

```
Updated error log:



 [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building API 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ API >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ API ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\aayus\workspace_neon\API\src\main\resources
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\aayus\workspace_neon\API\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ API ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ API ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\aayus\workspace_neon\API\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ API ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ API <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ API ---

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.2.RELEASE)

2017-04-22 11:55:08.626  INFO 12104 --- [           main] com.example.Application                  : Starting Application on DESKTOP-CAFJH2F with PID 12104 (C:\Users\aayus\workspace_neon\API\target\classes started by aayus in C:\Users\aayus\workspace_neon\API)
2017-04-22 11:55:08.630  INFO 12104 --- [           main] com.example.Application                  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-04-22 11:55:08.812  INFO 12104 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@75f09de6: startup date [Sat Apr 22 11:55:08 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-04-22 11:55:12.890  INFO 12104 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-04-22 11:55:12.936  INFO 12104 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-04-22 11:55:12.944  INFO 12104 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.6
2017-04-22 11:55:14.408  INFO 12104 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-04-22 11:55:14.409  INFO 12104 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5614 ms
2017-04-22 11:55:14.843  INFO 12104 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-04-22 11:55:14.870  INFO 12104 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-04-22 11:55:14.871  INFO 12104 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-04-22 11:55:14.872  INFO 12104 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-04-22 11:55:14.872  INFO 12104 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-04-22 11:55:15.677  INFO 12104 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@75f09de6: startup date [Sat Apr 22 11:55:08 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-04-22 11:55:15.794  INFO 12104 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api],consumes=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.String com.example.Controller.insertData(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws org.json.simple.parser.ParseException,java.io.IOException
2017-04-22 11:55:15.798  INFO 12104 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-04-22 11:55:15.799  INFO 12104 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-04-22 11:55:15.861  INFO 12104 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-04-22 11:55:15.861  INFO 12104 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-04-22 11:55:15.971  INFO 12104 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-04-22 11:55:16.403  INFO 12104 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-04-22 11:55:16.651 ERROR 12104 --- [           main] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol      : Failed to start end point associated with ProtocolHandler [http-nio-8080]

java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:228) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:874) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:969) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:233) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:178) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:297) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:145) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545) [spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at com.example.Application.main(Application.java:18) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:506) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]

2017-04-22 11:55:16.659 ERROR 12104 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]

org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:233) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:178) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:297) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:145) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545) [spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at com.example.Application.main(Application.java:18) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:506) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: service.getName(): "Tomcat";  Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:976) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:228) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:874) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:969) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    ... 20 common frames omitted

2017-04-22 11:55:16.719  INFO 12104 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2017-04-22 11:55:16.854  INFO 12104 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-04-22 11:55:16.862 ERROR 12104 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8080, or configure this application to listen on another port.

2017-04-22 11:55:16.864  INFO 12104 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@75f09de6: startup date [Sat Apr 22 11:55:08 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-04-22 11:55:16.865  INFO 12104 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:506)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.ConnectorStartFailedException: Connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.checkThatConnectorsHaveStarted(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:205)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:183)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:297)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
    at com.example.Application.main(Application.java:18)
    ... 6 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 24.928 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-22T11:55:16+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/137M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project API: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Why you excluded the spring-boot-starter-tomcat dependency in your pom.xml? Tomcat is the default container used by spring and excluding spring-boot-starter-tomcat will break the spring boot module.

Comment: Sorry! it's applicationContextException @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: There's a pretty clear error message: _Unable to start `EmbeddedWebApplicationContext` due to missing `EmbeddedServletContainerFactory` bean._ What do you think that means?

Comment: As far as I understood,I can either deploy the servlet on spring-boot internal server or exclusively on tomcat too! That's why I did it.What is the correct way of doing it? @NaveenKumar

Comment: I am not sure @SotiriosDelimanolis

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the [Traditional Deployment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html) documentation of Spring Boot.

To stop the embedded servlet container from interfering with the target container you need to change packaging to `war` (which you have done) and mark the embedded runtime as as "provided" scope.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Do not exclude it.

Comment: what should I do if I get port number issue in the embedded server.With an external server,I can always change it, but with an embedded server how can it be done @Strelok

Comment: I am still getting InvocationTargetException and ConnectorStartFailedException

Comment: @aayushi Well, now it's starting, you just have something else running on port 8080. You can change the port by setting `server.port` to something else in your `application.properties` or run the app with `-Dserver.port=<some_other_port>`. Btw, you should also remove the `<exclusions>` element from your POM.

Comment: okay,I will remove that and do I need to make a separate application.properties file for configuring the port number @Strelok

Comment: @aayushi if you already have one then you don't need to create it, just place it in your existing one. If you don't you can either create it in `src/main/resources` or use the runtime `-Dserver.port` option to override.

Answer (score 0):

Spring-boot by default starts tomcat container. But in your pom you are excluding it. And you are not specifying any other container as well. Either remove this exclusion or add this dependency to start jetty

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Even after adding this dependency,I am getting these exceptions: ApplicationContextException,NoClassDefFoundError and InvocationTargetException

Answer (score -2):

you are not use `@ImportResourcetry` into start of the class please try this code.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:abc-server.xml")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think this will make any difference? What is `abc-server.xml`?

Comment: What does @ImportResourcetry do? and how do you it is effecting my code as I have done all the configuration in my classes only!